# How to recognise I2c patterns from the scope

Tags: embedded

The scope photos shown below are from I2c communication with [Si7021 sensor](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf) shown below.

From the [reference manual page 482 of EFR32FG14](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf) the start and stop are as shown below.

I am sending measure command with slave address as shown in the code below.

In the end I am supposed to recieve LS MS and checksum bytes.

I can't see those parts.

Could you please draw on my scope photo the START, the ACK, and the recieved data and stop parts?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
#include "stddef.h"

#include "em_system.h"

#include "em_device.h"

#include "em_chip.h"

#include "em_cmu.h"

#include "em_emu.h"

#include "em_gpio.h"

#include "i2cspm.h"

#include "si7013.h"

#include "sl_sleeptimer.h"

#include "graphics.h"

#include "em_adc.h"

#include "bspconfig.h"





uint8_t com1[1] = {0xE3};

uint8_t i2c_rxBuffer[3];

int main(void)

{

I2C_TransferSeq_TypeDef i2cTransfer;

I2C_TransferReturn_TypeDef result;



I2CSPM_Init_TypeDef i2cInit = I2CSPM_INIT_DEFAULT;





/* Chip errata */

CHIP_Init();



// Enabling clock to the I2C, GPIO, LE

CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_I2C0, true);

CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);

CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_HFLE, true);



// Starting LFXO and waiting until it is stable

CMU_OscillatorEnable(cmuOsc_LFXO, true, true);



I2CSPM_Init(&i2cInit);

// In order to enable the I2C0_SCL function in PC10 you need to use ROUTE 14

// In order to enable the I2C0_SDA function in PC11 you need to use ROUTE 16

//Also note that there's a GPIO pin PD15 that need to be set to high in order to route the signals to the sensor,

// Using PC10 (SCL) and PC11 (SDA)

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 10, gpioModeWiredAndPullUp, 1);

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 11, gpioModeWiredAndPullUp, 1);



  //Si7021 switch on

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortD, 15, gpioModePushPull, 1);



  // Enable pins at location 15 as specified in datasheet

  I2C0->ROUTEPEN = I2C_ROUTEPEN_SDAPEN | I2C_ROUTEPEN_SCLPEN;

  I2C0->ROUTELOC0 = (I2C0->ROUTELOC0 & (~_I2C_ROUTELOC0_SDALOC_MASK)) | I2C_ROUTELOC0_SDALOC_LOC16;

  I2C0->ROUTELOC0 = (I2C0->ROUTELOC0 & (~_I2C_ROUTELOC0_SCLLOC_MASK)) | I2C_ROUTELOC0_SCLLOC_LOC14;

  i2cTransfer.flags=I2C_FLAG_WRITE_READ;

  i2cTransfer.addr=0x80;//address with write

  i2cTransfer.buf[0].data=com1[0];  // Measure Temperature, Hold Master Mode

  i2cTransfer.buf[0].len=2;    //2 bytes length



  i2cTransfer.buf[1].data=i2c_rxBuffer;

  i2cTransfer.buf[1].len=3;    //LS MS checksum

while(1)

{

  result=I2C_TransferInit(I2C0,&i2cTransfer);



  // Sending data

   while (result == i2cTransferInProgress)

   {

    result = I2C_Transfer(I2C0);

   }

}



}
```

Comment: pictures 3 and 4 it is pretty obvious where the start pattern is.  you can count out the clocks, see where on the data line the signal moves a smidge?  That is where the spot where the slave acks the master has released its pull on the line and the slave takes over and/or you dont have a pull up (the signal being high before implies a pull up but maybe the master is push/pull).

Comment: It's hard to see if the whole protocol sequence is correct. You should zoom out to see a whole transaction. But it is for sure from even the first command bits that command sent to chip is not correct 0xE3, as the data line just stays low after sending slave address. Is this just standard how to use pointers in C error? @old_timer the shark-fin shape or RC rising edges and sharp falling edges indicates it is not push-pull output.

Comment: @Justme yep understood, could be the circuit too.

Comment: Hello, Why its a problem to send data this way as shown bellow?
How should i do it so it will be send correctly on I2C sequence.
uint8_t com1[1] = {0xE3};
i2cTransfer.buf[0].data=com1[0];

Comment: You should check if .data must be a pointer to your data or data itself. You simply set .data to 0xE3 which is wrong if .data must be a pointer to address where the 0xE3 is stored. Later when you read stuff, you set .data to be pointer to address of buffer. I don't know which one is right, but I assume .data is a pointer since you can transfer multiple bytes. Doesn't the compiler warn about this? Do you have compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: Yes, the `data` member of [I2C_TransferSeq_TypeDef](https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/efm32g/html/structI2C__TransferSeq__TypeDef.html) is a pointer.  `com1[0]` is not a pointer.  `com1` is a pointer.  And `&com1[0]` is a pointer.

Comment: Also, I suspect `buf[0].len` should be 1, not 2.  Only 1 byte, the measure command byte, should be written.